# How to Solve The Redundant Literal Rule (OR)?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I found on the internet this rule **(A + B = A + A̅ B)** and its called **Redundant Literal Rule**. this is it's **OR form.** But I want to know is this really form of the Redundant Literal Rule?. I saw in a website there are 2 Types in this Law. What do you think about that. Is that true? (proves can add as comments)

Comment: What is $A, B$? What is $+$? What is $\overline{A}$? In what "space" all of that happens? There's not enough info to understand the question.

Comment: I do not believe that the algebraic topology tag is appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $$A + A'B = A (1) + A'B = A (1 + B) + A'B $$ $$= A + AB + A'B = A + B (A + A')$$ $$= A+B (1) = A + B $$ where $A'$ is the complement of $A $. Hope it helps.

Comment: hi, can you please describe every step with the rule/law you applied?
tks

Answer (score 0):

A + A̅B

= (A + AB) + A̅B           (Rule : A = A + AB)

= A + (AB + A̅B)

Taking B common,

= A + B (A +A̅)

= A + B                          (Rule : A + A̅ = 1)

Comment: Mine pleasure :-)